# Android Swipe to Refresh Animation Keeps Spinning

Tags: android

I have implemented a swipe to refresh in one of my fragments. The problem is that the refresh icon keeps spinning and doesn't refresh the list. I have implemented the `onRefresh()` to call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` but this doesn't seem to refresh the list

**Populating the list & swipe view**

```
    swipe = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipe);
    swipe.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    cursor = db.getAllItems();
    String[] values = new String[cursor.getCount()];
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    for(int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++)
    {
        String row = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
        values[i] = row;
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

final String[] columns = new String[] {db.KEY_ITEM_NAME, db.KEY_MEASUREMENT, db.KEY_UNIT};

    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.ingredientName, R.id.ingredientMeasurement, R.id.ingredientUnit};

    adapter = new ShoppingCustomAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.shopping_list_row, cursor, columns, to);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

**onRefresh**

```
@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to:

```
@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    swipe.setRefreshing(false);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```